# Connecting centos server through Putty

Tags: ssh, vmware

I have been facing following problem for several days, but i can't find an exact solution.
So I have Centos server on Vmware Workstation and i want make a ssh connection  through Putty. But i receive following error.

[image]

It also occurs when i try to use mRemoteNG, WinSCP and other tools like that.
Some guys say  that change keepalives from 0 to anything, and enable TCP keepalives on Putty. But it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly host and application configuration is off-topic here.  You can try asking on [sf] for a professional system, or [su] for a personal one.  Be prepared to provide your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, I have used a workaround instead. Have two network adapters for the VM:
First Network Adapter - Bridge Mode (So you are connected to internet - Define the default gateway). If DHCP is running on your internet router, it will be auto assigned.
Second Network Adapter - Host Adapter with any VMNet (e.g. VMNet1)- with Static/DHCP Pool on it (Don't give a default gateway in OS because out bound traffic may confuse).

In this way from putty, you can connect from your host computer via Second Network Adapter or you can connect from different computer via the internet router on the First Network Adapter.